# SQL Server Data Files in Microsoft Azure pricing

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-storage

I have a VM in Azure running SQL server and I am investigating storing my SQL data and log files directly in Azure premium storage as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/sql-server-data-files-in-microsoft-azure

I have been able to get this up and running fairly painlessly and given the benefits of the snapshot backups and quickly scaling the VM, I plan to continue with this however there is one issue I cannot seem to find an answer for and that is what the costs are.

All the documentation related to pricing for Azure Premium storage talks about disks, and that you are charged the cost rounded up to the next largest disk size but it is unclear if this also applies to page blobs that are not disks.

So my question is essentially, if I have a database with a 400GB data file and a 20GB log file, does that equate to one P20 disk and one P10 disk (in which case I should make the log file 128GB), or am I charged for a single P20 disk because the combined size of the two files is 420GB?

Secondly, how does premium storage deal with file growth?  With disks it is more straight forward as I don't believe you can dynamically resize them, but what happens when you have an SQL server data file with auto-growth turned on as a page blob in premium storage and it grows over the size threshold of it's current disk? e.g 500GB file auto-grows by 10% to 550GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is essentially, if I have a database with a 400GB data
>   file and a 20GB log file, does that equate to one P20 disk and one P10
>   disk (in which case I should make the log file 128GB), or am I charged
>   for a single P20 disk because the combined size of the two files is
>   420GB?

According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-premium-storage#pricing-and-billing).

**Billing for a premium storage disk or blob depends on the provisioned size of the disk or blob. Azure maps the provisioned size (rounded up) to the nearest premium storage disk option.**

If you store your data file and log file on a single disk. Your data is 420GB, you need pay for P20(512GB) cost. If you store your data file and log file as two disks, you need pay for P20(512GB) and P6(64GB) cost. You also could refer my [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/820315/azure-c-drive-pricing/820346#820346) similar with this.

More information about Premium Managed Disks price please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/).

> Secondly, how does premium storage deal with file growth?

Currently, Azure does not support auto-grows data disk size, you could use cmdlet to increase disk size, please refer to this [link] for more detailsl

```
az disk update \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myDataDisk \
    --size-gb 200
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks).

Update:

P10 and P20 are premium storage account, I check the link you provided, you should use standard storage account. Please refer to this [link:Azure Storage Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/blobs/).

Comment: @Eamon Now, Azure Provides P4(32GB), P6(64GB) Premium disk, you could select them, they are more cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the response Walter, your answer raises a few more questions though. Firstly, are the P4 and P6 sizes generally available?  The pricing portal does not show them https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/unmanaged-disks/

Comment: Ok, I've found P4 and P6 under "Managed Disks" option and a note in another document that "P4 and P6 disk sizes are yet only supported for Managed Disks"  so it seems that they can't be used in this situation.

Comment: @Eamon Your VM uses managed disk or unmanaged disk, if your VM uses managed disk, according to your scenario, you could use P6, it is more cheaper.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the main premise of the question and that is that I am not using a disks at all.  I have SQL server running in a VM (which has an OS disk, but I am not talking about this) and I have copied the data and log files to a premium storage account as page blobs.  I am then directly attaching a database to these files.  This scenario is poorly documented in Azure.  Are my page blob files (which are NOT vhd's) treated as un-managed disks?

Comment: @Eamon Sorry for my mistake, do you mean you store your sql file as page blobs not a VHD mount on VM? I guess it will produce many blobs in storage account. `Billing for a premium storage disk or blob depends on the provisioned size of the disk or blob.`. You need pay for every blobs, even they are only 1MB, you also need pay for P10 cost.  Based on my understanding `premium storage` is design for High Performance(SSD OS disk and data disk), it is not use for store data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152978/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-eamon).

Comment: Thanks Walter, I am glad we're on the same page now :)  If you see the article I linked at the top of my question, at least some in MSFT are recommending it for this specific scenario for a variety of reasons.  I'll take further responses to chat.